# Trouble with Tornado and JavaScript Libraries

Tags: javascript, python, templates, tornado, protovis

I'm trying to write a simple python web application using the Tornado web server and am having trouble using the JavaScript libraries I need. I wanted to use the Protovis JavaScript plotting library, so I added the following 'Hello World' code snippet to my template.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/protovis-d3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript+protovis">
new pv.Panel()
    .width(150)
    .height(150)
    .anchor("center")
    .add(pv.Label)
        .text("Hello, world!")
        .root.render();
</script>
```

Whenever I run the webserver, however, and try accessing the page, I get the following error at the console:

```
WARNING:root:404 GET /protovis-d3.2.js (127.0.0.1) 0.46ms
```

The protovis.js file is in the same directory as my server.py file, and all its permissions are set correctly. I get the same error when trying to src and JavaScript file so I know there isn't a problem with the protovis.js file, but something with the Tornado server's routing.

Does anyone know how I can properly src this JavaScript code, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should read the documentation about [static files](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.4/overview.html?highlight=static%20path#static-files-and-aggressive-file-caching).

In particular, the standard way is to:

- Create a 'static' directory in the root of your application
- Add the following to your application settings:

  "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), "static")
- Put the **protovis-d3.2.js** in your static directory
- Refer to the file **/static/protovis-d2.2.js** in your HTML