# Local CSS and JS files not linking to html pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, tornado

I have a base html file which I want all other pages to inherit certain charateristics from. But although my inherited pages eg. `main.html` can reference external links eg:

```
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

With no problem. But when I try to download the twitter bootstrap and store the file in the same directory as all the other html pages it cannot link to that file and it gives me a 404 error. My file structure is simple; a folder called templates with all the html, css and js files in this directory.

So i'm doing this:

```
 <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

When I try to do this:

```
<link href="http://localhost/templates/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

I get no `404` error, but from the view source on the web page, if I try to access that page I get an error saying:

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at .

I'm really lost to why this 'simple' thing is not working.

Comment: so it needs to be `/templates/bootstrap.css`?

Comment: Thanks, if I do that it gives me the 404 GET error.

Comment: html and css files are in the same folder?

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but do you have a web server running on localhost?

Comment: Yes html and css are all in the same folder. Yes I have a web server running, so I can view the webpages fine.

Comment: you need to keep `link` inside `head` element and try to remoce `media="screen"` attribute, maybe that will help

Comment: It's in the head tag and I removed media=screen but still no sucess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a `base` tag inside your html? If so, it could be saying firefox a specific host where to find files, different than localhost.
Try use Firebug on Firefox or Chrome developer tools to see which URLs it's trying to retrieve.

Comment: What is the complete URL it's trying to load ? Do you have a `base` tag?

Comment: [14:00:04.908] GET http://localhost:8888/bootstrap.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms] Is the error in firebug. All other html pages inherit from base by {% extends "base.html" %} - which is the syntax for the Tornado framework.

Comment: If you try to see that page directly from that URL, do you see it?

Comment: Maybe it's the problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167109/trouble-with-tornado-and-javascript-libraries 
I've never used Tornado, but it seems it uses the same method of Flask to manage static files.

Comment: Ok I'll give that a go and put css and js files into the static folder. Thanks

Comment: Thanks that worked: I included a static directory for the css and js files and in the tornado server referred to it by:   static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")

Comment: Glad to hear,I'm learning Flask and it has a similar mechanism, but although I read the docs, probably I would have done the same error.

Comment: At least we know.....if you set everything up correctly at the beginning then it makes things so much easier. Now I've done it, it makes sense now. Thanks for your help.